# Add multiple option values for git config option

Tags: git

I can add manually the following to the git config:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    mergeOptions = --edit --no-ff
```

However, when I try to add the same using command line like this:

```
$ git config branch.master.mergeOptions --edit --no-ff
```

Only the first `--edit` values are added to the config. How to add both `--edit` and `--no-ff`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the `--edit --no-ff` with quotes:

```
$ git config branch.master.mergeOptions "--edit --no-ff"
```

This will make it work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, now the merge brings up an editor and I put new message for the merge commit but the default `Merged...` message is recorded to the commit. Do you know what might be the reason for this?

Comment: I don't know. I assume Git forces this to make sure you later see this was a merge commit.